# how to define route in navigator.pop

Tags: flutter

class Verification extends StatelessWidget {
const Verification({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return MaterialApp(
debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
home: Scaffold(
body: Padding(
padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 30,left: 20),
child: Column(
children: [
Row(
children: [
InkWell(
onTap: (){
Navigator.pop(context);
},
child: Image.asset(
"assets/images/vector.png",
scale: 2.5,
),
),
SizedBox(
width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.2,
),
Text(
"Verification",
style: TextStyle(fontSize: 28, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
),
],
),
Padding(
padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 15),
child: Row(
mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
children: [
Text("Enter your"
,style: TextStyle(fontSize: 48, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),),
],
),
),Row(
mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
children: [
Text("Verification Code"
,style: TextStyle(fontSize: 48, fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),),
],
),

```
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

}
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not define a route in navigator.pop, you can only go back one page.
If you want to go back a few Screen, you can use

```
nav = Navigator.of(context);
nav.pop();
nav.pop();
```